# CiviCRM translations on staging server not working

Tags: drupal, civicrm-home, translation

We made a copy of the live site for making a staging site. We did the updates and everything is working fine. Except for te translations not working (anymore).

Under 'CiviCRM » Localization » Languages, Currency, Locations' we set Default Language to Dutch (Nederlands). After the updates we saw that in the Civi module folders "l10n" and "sql" where empty. So i copied the files back from the production environment en put them back.

From documentation, this should be it to make it work but everything is still in english.
After searching for a full day i don't know where to look anymore. Resource url should be ok and no other errors on the site.

Searching online for this problem does not give much results.

Information:
Drupal V7.69
CiviCRM V5.23.3

Thanks

Comment: Hi Joris, just to be complete: did you check the "inherit CMS language" tick? If that is switched on and Drupal is in English so will CiviCRM. (en mocht je er niet uitkomen kun je ook onze helpdesk bellen om even mee te kijken?)

Comment: Also just try re-saving the localization settings page. Also check in civicrm.settings.php if you have a define('CIVICRM_L10N_BASEDIR') or a $civicrm_paths['civicrm.l10n'] set.

Comment: Thanks for response. "inherit CMS language" tick is not checked. And Drupal is also set in dutch so that would not be a problem i think.
Re-saving the localization settings page did not work. 
There is no define('CIVICRM_L10N_BASEDIR') or a $civicrm_paths['civicrm.l10n'] set in civicrm.settings.php but neither on the production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using "native gettext"? If yes, the staging server might not have the locales enabled on the operating system (ex: `dpkg --configure locales`).

The [symbiotic](https://civicrm.org/extensions/symbiotic) extension might help debug the issue. There are extra status checks for common translation problems. Once enabled, go to Administer > Administration Console > System Status.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still busy with this you can better download the latest version of the translation from the download-page CiviCRM: the localization files. The directory sql is only used for new installments, so the l10n-part will do.
You can switch the language first to English to force the system to re-translate the menu and set then the language back.
I have a working extension (standalone) to update the translation using the sql-file for single language systems, you can then use the latest translations for upgraded CiviCRM installments because great parts of CiviCRM are only translated during the installation and the translation in Transifex is always behind the new versions of CiviCRM. Let me know if you want to try my extension on your development system.